# Derivation of integral

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, partial-differential-equations

I have a problem with understanding one step of an excercise. I don't get why this equality holds $\frac{d}{dt}\int^{b(t)}_{a(t)}u(t,x)dx=\int^{b(t)}_{a(t)}\partial_t u(t,x)dx +\frac{d}{dt}b(t)u(t,b(t))-\frac{d}{dt}a(t)u(t,a(t))$

Comment: This come from Liebniz's integral rule, you may check the proof on wiki https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule

Comment: the full proof is actually in this article: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differentiation_under_the_integral_sign